# How to scroll in a webpage with "easeOutExpo" animation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, parallax.js

I am trying to add [easeOutExpo](http://commadot.com/jquery/easing.php) effect while scrolling in a webpage

I originally found this in a website http://www.loisjeans.com/web2012/js/parallax.js 
I tried a lot  to bring the effect ,but in vain.

Is there any simple way to implement animation effects while scrolling.please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [iscroll4](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/) may help this for your question supports in all browsers easy to implement.

Comment: hmmmm... unfortunately i did not find any way to implement easing functions in that script.anyways ,thanks a lot for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Smooth scroll supports easing: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll
Should match your needs:

```
$.smoothScroll({
    scrollTarget: '#yourdiv'
    easing: "easeOutExpo"
});
```

Comment: i wanted the effect every time onscroll and not when some1 hits one button...anyways.......thanks a lot......